# Use Xcode Shared Library Project for Static Library

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a C++ project which is compiled to a universal shared library. Now, I also want a static library for the same. I tried to reuse the shared library Xcode project but the size of static library created is much smaller (~ 3MB) as compared to when I create a separate Xcode Static Library project to compile my code (~19 MB).

Here is what I tried with the shared library project:

```
xcodebuild -project MyLibrary.xcodeproj build MACH_O_TYPE=staticlib EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION=a GCC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_SEPARATION=NO PACKAGE_TYPE=com.apple.package-type.static-library
```

I don't want to maintain two Xcode project files just for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The library generated using above method works fine and is a valid static library.

```
xcodebuild -project MyLibrary.xcodeproj build MACH_O_TYPE=staticlib EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION=a GCC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_SEPARATION=NO PACKAGE_TYPE=com.apple.package-type.static-library
```

For details refer [Much larger static library generated by xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770110/much-larger-static-library-generated-by-xcode)