# Much larger static library generated by xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, static-libraries

I have a C++ project which is compiled to a universal shared library. Now, I also want a static library for the same. When I reuse the shared library Xcode project to create static library, the size of static library created is much smaller (~ 3MB) as compared to when I create a separate Xcode Static Library project to compile my code (**~19 MB)**. (universal - 32 & 64 bit)

Here is what I tried with the shared library project:

```
xcodebuild -project MyLibrary.xcodeproj build MACH_O_TYPE=staticlib EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION=a GCC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_SEPARATION=NO PACKAGE_TYPE=com.apple.package-type.static-library
```

Both the libraries work fine when linked to any C++ project. `otool` gives same output for both libraries

Also, I tried creating the static build using Qt Creator and again the library size was around 3 MB (32 + 64 bit)

I wonder what is the difference between the two static libraries if they both link fine.

The size of the same static library when compiled on Linux is aroung ~4MB (32 + 64 bit)

Comment: My guess is that the static library project has some sort of compiler optimization like loop unrolling.

Comment: @IanPudney I am using almost the same settings in both shared as well as static project files. How can I verify if loop unrolling is enabled

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about XCode to be able to tell you. Try explicitly making debug builds of both projects (a build with symbols), try a non-debug build without optimizations, or a non-debug build with optimizations. Though you probably checked that stuff first.

Comment: That kind of size difference indicates that something "ain't right" in some settting somewhere. Figuring out what may not be so easy... :(